# Keyboard Shortcut: How to switch to previously active windows in another workspace

Tags: shortcut-keys, 20.04, workspaces, window, application-switcher

I have `google-chrome` (and other software) in Workspace 2 and `thunderbird` (and other software) in Workspace 3.

How can I switch to previously active windows in another workspace, using keybpard shortcuts? For example, if google-chrome was active before I switched to thunderbird, how can I switch back to google-chrome?

---

### NOTE

`Alt` + `Tab`:  Cycles through windows in the same workspace

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting that allows the Window Switcher cycle through windows on all workspaces. You can set it as following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false
```

To set so only windows of the current workspace are shown:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

The application by default switches across workspaces.

Comment: I did what you said. I reloaded my Gnome shell by pressing `Alt` + `F2` and then typing r. But no changes happened. And I did: `$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only 
false`

Comment: Can you give me the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications` and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows`?

Comment: `$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications
['<Super>Tab']` and
`$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows
['<Alt>Tab']`

Comment: Then the command I gave should do it. Double check or use dconf-editor to change the value.

Comment: I checked my dconf editor, where `current-workspace-only` is `true`. But, why `gsettings` commands are not modifying my dconf? Could you please suggest?